# Spring Cloud AWS Autoconfiguration Credentials

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

I am having some trouble with `org.springframework.cloud.aws.autoconfigure.context.ContextCredentialsAutoConfiguration`

When running my app locally inside Docker with the following environment variables set:

```
cloud.aws.credentials.accessKey=xxx
cloud.aws.credentials.secretKey=yyy
```

my app works as I expect. However, when I run it on docker on an EC2 instance with the same environment variables the app fails when calling SQS due to the not having permission.

I have set:

```
cloud.aws.stack.auto=false
cloud.aws.credentials.instance.profile=false
```

both locally and on EC2.

Should I define my own `com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProvider` bean or should the default auto config behaviour be enough? I am confused about why the auto config seems to be favouring an instance profile or some other credentials over the ones provided via the environment.

Comment: Could you share an error which you got on EC2?